# Odoo 11 - Filter a Many2One field

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I have 2 fields which point to 2 different models.

```
class ResPartnerSchool(models.Model):
    _name = 'ecole.partner.school'
    foyer_id = fields.Many2one(string="Foyer", comodel_name="horanet.relation.foyer",
                               domain="[('partner_id','=', partner_id)]", store=True, readonly=False)
    partners_in_foyer_id = fields.Many2one(string="Name", comodel_name="res.partner", readonly=False, store=True)
```

I will like to recover the partners who are in the home that I recovered from my form.
[image]

I managed to do an onchange () function to automatically retrieve one of the household members.

```
@api.onchange('foyer_id')
def get_partners_foyer(self):
    if self.foyer_id:
        foyer = self.foyer_id.foyer_id
        domain = [('foyer_id', '=', foyer.id)]
        members = self.foyer_id.search(domain, limit=1)
        if not members :
            _logger.info(f"Pas de membres trouvés pour : {self.partner_id.name}")
        else:
            if members.partner_id:
                self.partners_in_foyer_id = members.partner_id.id
```

But how do you get all the household members and display them in the xml view? Currently, all the partners of the res.partner table are retrieved in the view.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

First you put one `flag(boolean type)` in `res.partner` for `home`, and then use this domain `(domain="[('home','=', True)]")` in your `Many2one(partners_in_foyer_id)` field.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you explain ?

Comment: put one boolean field in res.partner which depend on household, if your partner is household then it true otherwise it false. and use domain in you many2one field to filter only household partners.